# "Je näher man ein Wort ansieht, desto ferner sieht es zurück."

Tags: german-to-english, interpretation

I'm wondering how to correctly understand this phrase:

> Je näher man ein Wort ansieht, desto ferner sieht es zurück.
>
> <sup>*Karl Kraus (1874 - 1936), Quote from the magazine [»Die Fackel«,  July 8, 1911.](https://fackel.oeaw.ac.at/f/326,044)*</sup>

To me it seems that it can be undertood in 2 different senses.

The first would be quite literal: "The closer you look at a word, the farther back it seems to be [looks like]".

The second would be: "The closer you look at a word, the farther *it* looks back at *you*".

Am I correct in assuming both interpretations are in order?

Comment: This looks philosophic, which means context is very important. Please share the source of this quote.

Comment: I added the source. @flen: Please for your next questions: If you quote a text, please also give the source, or at least the context from which this sentence was torn, so that those who want to answer your question can better understand this text.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Thank you for adding the source! I read it as a free standing epigraph in Hanna Pitkin's "The Concept of Representation" (a work in political philosophy which borrows a lot from philosophy of language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal meaning is this:

> The closer you look at a word, the farther it looks back (at you).

The part *"at you"* (*zu dir*) is not necessary in German, but I think the English translation would be incomplete without it (English is not my native language, so I'm not sure).

The figurative meaning is this:

> The more you try to analyze a particular word, the stranger it seems. By trying to approach the word, it seems to become all the more unapproachable.

Karl Kraus, the author of this sentence, published it as a note in his satirical magazine *Die Fackel*, which he edited from 1899 until his death in 1936 in Vienna, where he lived. This magazine is, beside the drama [Die letzten Tage der Menschheit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_letzten_Tage_der_Menschheit) (*The Last Days of Mankind*), the main work of Karl Kraus. In this magazine is a section titled *»Pro domo et mundo«* (this is latin and translates to English as: *"for the house and the world"* and means *"On my own and all others's behalf"*) and there he published such sentences as singular free-standing ideas. This particular sentence stands in issue 326-328 (three issues in one) from July 8, 1911 of *Die Fackel* on page 44.

---

It was also asked, if "desto ferner sieht es zurück" can be interpreted as "the farther back it seems to be".

The very clear and unambiguous answer is: **No.**

We have this pair of translations:

> 1. Es sieht zurück. = It looks back (at you).
> 2. Es sieht so aus. = It looks like. (It seems to be.)

The difference is the semantic role of the subject. The syntactic role is the same: Both sentences are in active voice, so the subject is the grammatical agent.

But semantically there is a huge difference:

Sentence 1 means, that the subject (it = the word) really actively does something: It slowly turns its head towards you, looks at you, opens its eyes wide and stares at you from a distance with an evil stare. The word has a mind and a will. It doesn't want to be watched. When you stare at it, it stares back. When you approach it, it moves away. It is a living being that reacts to its environment and would prefer to be left alone.

Sentence 2 is completely different: The subject (it = the word) is a completely passive entity. It does nothing but just exist. Others look at at it and others see it. Those others get the unreal impression that the word moves away when they approach, but in fact the word does absolutely nothing. The word is just a lifeless bunch of letters, not even able to perceive what is happening around it, let alone react to it in any way.

Karl Kraus very clearly wanted to express the first meaning, not the second. - Keep in mind that this sentence was published by a famous satirist in a satirical magazine.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Do you also think there could be a reading of the stretch "desto ferner sieht es zurück" as in "the farther back it seems to be" (bzw. "desto ferner zurück[?] sieht es so aus")? Now that I read your answer this reading seems to me completely wrong, even though the meaning of the sentence is similar

Answer (score 1):

The correct translation is

> The closer you look at a word, the farther it looks backward.

There is no notion of  "looks back to you" in the German sentence. Adding it is an act of interpretation, and I think, this interpretation is not backed by the structure of the sentence.

A better interpretation is "The closer you inspect a word, the more you realize about its history and etymology."

This is backed by the fact that the sentence reads

> desto ferner sieht es zurück.

A meaning of "the more it looks back to you" would rather be expressed by saying *desto **mehr** sieht es zurück*. But the sentence uses *ferner*. *fern* means "distant"  and its use would be hard to explain in reading the sentence in a way that the word would be looking back to "you".

Comment: While I agree with much of this, there are not many other objects besides the mentioned observer, that the word could look (back?) to. I understood the sentence as funny assumption, that observer and word are counterparts of the same level. One could avoid the problem by translating *the more distant it (the word) appears*, but  ...

Comment: Your interpretation, I think, is disproved by the context. While these epigrams are formally independent of each other, in this case the one right above is just too closely related: "Ein Satz kann nie zur Ruhe kommen. Nun sitzt dies Wort, denke ich, und wird sich nicht mehr rühren. Da hebt das nächste seinen Kopf und lacht mich an. Ein drittes stößt ein viertes. Die ganze Bank schabt mir Rübchen. Ich laufe hinaus; wenn ich wiederkomme, ist alles ruhig; und wenn ich unter sie trete, geht der Lärm los."